# send a message to a vehicle by using omnet++ and sumo

Tags: communication, omnet++, veins, sumo, vehicle-routing

I would like to use SUMO and OMNeT++ to send a message to a vehicle using the VEINS framework. For example, I want to change the route or direct a vehicle to a specific destination by using a Roadside Unit (RSU). Can someone provide me with instructions on how to do this or suggest where I can start? I would appreciate an example or any guidance.
Thank you

Can someone provide me with instructions on how to do this or suggest where I can start? I would appreciate an example or any guidance